# Customized rendering of SVGs in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, batik

I am working on a java swing application that requires rendering images in specific locations on a `JPanel`.  Currently, I am using PNG images with the `Graphics.drawImage` method.  The application also requires the ability to freely move and zoom the "camera", which I am accomplishing with the `Graphics2D.scale` and `Graphics2D.translate` methods.

However, a significant issue with this approach is that the images do not scale well when the application is zoomed in.  I was hoping that I could get around this by using SVGs, so I downloaded the Batik library.  I have been able to display an SVG using Batik's `SVGCanvas`, but this doesn't really solve my problem because I am unable to freely place the SVGs in the `JPanel` and use the SVGs alongside the java `Graphics` methods.

Does Batik even apply to my use case?  If not, is there some other way I can freely scale and render SVGs in a JPanel just like I would with a `BufferedImage`? Another option would be to just use the `Graphics2D` methods to try to replicate the icons I want to use, but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: [Twelve Monkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) by _haraldk_ has a batik plugin for Java's `ImageIO` class.

Comment: The plugin works well for making a BufferedImage from an SVG, but that doesn't completely solve the program since the BufferedImage still needs to be generated with some specific resolution.  I ended up using [Flamingo SVG Transcoder](http://ebourg.github.io/flamingo-svg-transcoder/)  to convert the SVGs to java graphics calls, which is working well.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for the benefit of others who may find themselves in similar situation to yours.